# How to make a content type a Ubercart product

Tags: nodes, ubercart

Basically I want to add the "add to cart" button to a content type.
I've got Ubercart installed and enabled.
Normally whilst editing a content type there should be a section 
"ubercart product settings" where I can check "products... are shippable"

But there's no such section to make it a ubercart product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to admin/store/products/classes.

From there you'll be able to assign a product class to an existing content type, after which you should see the Ubercart-specific settings on the content type edit form.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7 and Ubercart 3, and all you can do from this page is create a new product. You can't assign to existing. why not?