# How to make an existing content type a product in Ubercart 3 and Drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart

This is a follow up to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97157/how-to-make-a-content-type-a-ubercart-product). If I go to admin/store/products/classes, then I can only create new content types:

[image]

The problem is, I have another content type, called "product", which I need to set as an UberCart product. And I create this class in ubercart that has now resulted in a new content typed called "Basic Product". When all I really want is for the existing product to be considered as an actual product.

When I edit the "product" content type, I can see it doesn't have the same options as the "basic product" content type:

[image]

So the question is: how do I make my EXISTING "product" content type an Uber Cart product? I checked under classes and that only seems to work if you want to create a NEW content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you simply tried to ***put the machine name of your existing content type*** in Class ID, and its human name in NAME ?

I've had such problem 3 years ago, and I solved it so. More, for tests purpose I've just created a *foo* content type. Then I added the Class ID *foo*, and it has been mapped with *foo* content type.

Comment: I did, and it threw another error. But it seems unrelated. So yes, it seems to just work by doing that. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Glad to know you had no worse trouble ;)